# Pass data to a cart page as a object with multiple values - state management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I'd like to pass a data i.e. `id`, `title` to a cart page as array of objects, but Typescript screaming at me that I did sth wrong, but i don't know what.

error(1):

> Argument of type '(state: CartState) => { carts: (string |
> SugarProductSchema)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'CartState | Partial | ((state: CartState) => CartState |
> Partial)'. Translation: I was expecting CartState |
> Partial | ((state: CartState) => CartState |
> Partial), but you passed (state: CartState) => { carts:
> (string | SugarProductSchema)[]; }

// zustand state management store

```js
import create from 'zustand';
import { devtools, persist } from 'zustand/middleware';
import { SugarProductSchema } from '@/types/sugar-product-schema';

interface CartState {
  carts: SugarProductSchema[];
  addToCart: (id: string, title: string) => void;
}

const useCartStore = create<CartState>()(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (set) => ({
        carts: [],
        addToCart: (id, title) =>
          set((state) => ({ carts: [...state.carts, id, title] })), // here is the error(1)
      }),
      {
        name: 'cart-storage',
      }
    )
  )
);

export default useCartStore;
```

product card component:

```js
// (...) 
const addToCart = useCartStore((state) => state.addToCart);

  const handleCartProducts = () => {
    addToCart(id, title);
    toast.success('Dodano produkt do koszyka');
    console.log(id);
  };
// (...)
```

Right now, it shows that error(1) which is mentioned above, but it still saves the data: e.g. `id` and `title` but in the way I don't want to: It's generating one array and adding values to this array instead of creating objects with `id` and `title` e.g.

[image]

it should like this:

```
[
 //product 1 {id:"t512521512", title:"random title"}
 //product 2 {id:"xxxxxx", title:"randosasasam title"}
//and so on

]
```

SugarProductSchema type file

```js
export type SugarProductSchema = {
  title: string;
  brand: string;
  price: number;
  coverImage: string;
  id: string;
  slug: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would guess the issue is that

```
set((state) => ({ carts: [...state.carts, id, title] }))
```

Isn't quite what you were wanting. You'll end up with something like

```
{ carts: [ cart1, cart2, cart3, id, title] }
```

Whereas that `set` function wants an array of `SugarProductSchema` and you're giving it `(string | SugarProductSchema)[]`. It's the rogue strings of `id` and `title` that are throwing it off.

Maybe what you're looking for is

```
set((state) => ({ carts: [ ...state.carts, { id, title } ] })
```

But then you're missing several fields from `SugarProductSchema` and it will be angry about that too. The main idea here is that the `carts` field in your `CartState` needs to be an array of `SugarProductSchema` types and nothing else.

If you just want the `id` and `title` to be required you might consider making the other fields in `SugarProductSchema` optional. Like

```
export type SugarProductSchema = {
  title: string;
  brand?: string;
  price?: number;
  coverImage?: string;
  id: string;
  slug?: string;
};
```

If they need to be required then you'll need to add those fields in when using `set`

Comment: Got another question: Can I type addToCart  in `CartState` interface like: `addToCart: (someType) => void` instead of  `addToCart: (id: string, title: string) => void;` ? because it will be the same types as are in  `SugarProductSchema[]`

Comment: Yeah as long as you realize that it's just one argument at that point instead of multiple. So you would do it like `addToCart(cart)` instead of the individual fields as arguments.